# Selecting which pages to display custom post type on using checkbox

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I have a custom post type called Testimonies. What I'm trying to do is allow a user to create a new Testimony and then select from a list of checkboxes which page(s) on the site he wants this testimony to display on.

I have managed to create the checkboxes to list all the site pages and code is below:

```
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init3");

function admin_init3(){ 
add_meta_box("credits_meta", "Choose on which pages to display",     "myplugin_inner_custom_box", "testimonies", "normal", "low");
}

function myplugin_inner_custom_box( $post ) {
// we store data as an array, we need to unserialize it
$checkfield = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID, "checkfield", true) );

// Nonce to verify intention later
wp_nonce_field( 'save_quote_meta', 'custom_nonce' ); 

$pages = get_pages(); 
foreach ( $pages as $page ) { ?>
    <input id="page_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" type="checkbox" name="checkfield[]" value="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" <?php if ( in_array($page->ID, (array) $checkfield) ) { ?> checked <?php } ?>/> <label for="page_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></label> <br>
<?php 
} 
}
//save the meta box action
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_meta_save', 10, 2 );

//save the meta box
function myplugin_meta_save($post_id, $post)
{   
if ( isset($_POST['checkfield']) ) { // if we get new data

    update_post_meta($post_id, "checkfield", $_POST['checkfield'] );

}
}
```

However, I'm having difficulty with the next step. My idea is to put the checkbox values in a variable, then check whether the current page id matches one of these values. If it does, I'll display the custom post. This is all a bit hazy though, and I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way.

Currently, I'm struggling to pass the checkbox values into a variable and echo these out. I have the below code but it's just echoing array, array, array, array.

```
<?php  $checkboxes=get_post_meta($post->ID, "checklist", false);
if ($checkboxes) {
foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox) {
echo  $checkbox;
}
} ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to run a foreach on a value inside the array. E.g. $checkboxes['value'] as $checkbox.. If you do: `print_r('$checkboxes')` you'll get an idea of the values you are trying to target. You might even have to do something like $checkboxes['something']['something_else'] depending on how many levels the array has.

Hope it helps, do a print_r and view source, or wrap it in pre tags I'm sure you'll figure out how to target the foreach then.